# How to access fields in model in view?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Hi I am new to Django and web development. I want to use the data in my model in order to do some calculations in views.py. What is the syntax required in views to access the data fields which is in the model?

Comment: Read the django documentation.

Comment: Read at least few lines of django documentation

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys, I did read the documentation but I I didn't understand which syntax is for my purpose as I'm new to coding.

Comment: At least do the tutorial, which tells you exactly how to do this. If you are totally new to coding, the Djangogirls tutorial will probably be better for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can import the models in your views file, then query the model objects to get the data you want. 
To name an example:

```
user_names = UserName.objects.all()

user_names = UserName.objects.filter(last_name='Smith')
```

Also, better to check the [official document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial04/).